# Unmanaged Code and Runtime Error 80131506 Winform .net

Tags: .net, crash, runtime, unmanaged, geckofx

i wish understand if the error 80131506 which make my application crash could be caused from a DLL Library GeckoFx (Wrapper Browser).

I think that has unmanaged code in many xpcom interface. Now i dont know how resolve and why i get this error. For who want understand what i'm talking about here the  [Link GeckoFX](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/)

There are many people that make browsers with this wrapper but i dont know why i'm the only that(maybe) recive this error.

I understood that could be an error of a Corruption Heap so it crashes when the garbage collector found something wrong.

The only strange thing that i do, it is the Dispose of all istance of GeckoWebBrowser inside my TabControl (like a button Close all Tab).

The problem is that i cant really understand when it become corrupted cause the crash could happen when it's running from 4 5 mins to 60 mins and i really still dont understand how get it. 
I used the CG.Collect() to cause the crashes more frequently but i still dont understand which is the problem.

Is there a way to handle this ?

Are there some attentions that i must follow when i write the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the hot fix here:
http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=2640103&kbln=en-us